# Java - Convert predicate to string

Tags: java, string, lambda, predicate

I would like to know if there is any way to convert a `Predicate` to `String`. For example there will be a function:

```
public static <T> String convertPredicate(Predicate<T> objPredicate) {
    return ?...
}
```

So that the following call will return `(obj) -> obj.value== 1`:

```
convertPredicate((obj) -> obj.value== 1)
```

Comment: There are some projects that use byte code analysis to attempt similar things: (1) from java expressions to SQL, (2) to generate JavaScript from java. However this would be a huge work of love, as an anonymous interface instance is generated in java. And certainly variable names must be artificial ones.

Comment: No, you cannot look and see "what's inside" a lambda and its implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in general it's not possible in Java. One may try to analyze and decompile the bytecode of the lambda class (though obtaining the bytecode of this class is already really non-trivial task), but such solution would be really complex and fragile. Particular runtime representation of the lambda is not specified and may change in different Java versions or different JDK vendors.